# Proper storage/retrieval of termVector

Tags: indexing, lucene, lucene.net

I'm using Lucene.NET 4.8-beta00005.

I have a "name" field in my documents defined as follows:

```
doc.Add(CreateField(NameField, entry.Name.ToLower()));
writer.AddDocument(doc);
```

Where `CreateField` is implemented as follows

```
private static Field CreateField(string fieldName, string fieldValue)
{
    return new Field(fieldName, fieldValue, new FieldType() {IsIndexed = true, IsStored = true, IsTokenized = true, StoreTermVectors = true, StoreTermVectorPositions = true, StoreTermVectorOffsets = true, StoreTermVectorPayloads = true});
}
```

The "name" field is assigned a `StandardAnalyzer`.

Then in my `CustomScoreProvider` I'm retriving the terms from the term vector as follows:

```
private List<string> GetDocumentTerms(int doc, string fieldName)
{
    var indexReader = m_context.Reader;
    var termVector = indexReader.GetTermVector(doc, fieldName);
    var termsEnum = termVector.GetIterator(null);

    BytesRef termBytesRef;
    termBytesRef = termsEnum.Next();

    var documentTerms = new List<string>();

    while (termBytesRef != null)
    {
        //removing trailing \0 (padded to 16 bytes)
        var termText = Encoding.Default.GetString(termBytesRef.Bytes).Replace("\0", "");
        documentTerms.Add(termText);
        termBytesRef = termsEnum.Next();
    }

    return documentTerms;
}
```

Now I have a document where the value of the "name" field is "dan gertler diamonds ltd."

So the terms from the term vector I'm expecting are:

> dan gertler diamonds ltd

But my `GetDocumentTerms` gives me the following terms:

> dan diamonds gertlers ltdtlers

I'm using as `StandardAnalyzer` with the field so I'm not expecting it to do much transformation to the orignal words in the field (and I did check with this particular name and StandardAnalyzer).

What am I doing wrong here and how to fix it?

**Edit:** I'm extracing the terms manually with each field's Analyzer and stroing the them in a separate String field as a workaroud for now.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the terms in correct order, you must also use the positional information. Test this code:

```
Terms terms = indexReader.GetTermVector(doc, fieldName);
if (terms != null)
{
    var termIterator = terms.GetIterator(null);
    BytesRef bytestring;
    var documentTerms = new List<Tuple<int, string>>();
    while ((bytestring = termIterator.Next()) != null)
    {
        var docsAndPositions = termIterator.DocsAndPositions(null, null, DocsAndPositionsFlags.OFFSETS);
        docsAndPositions.NextDoc();
        int position;
        for(int left = docsAndPositions.Freq; left > 0; left--)
        {
            position = docsAndPositions.NextPosition();
            documentTerms.Add(new Tuple<int, string>(position, bytestring.Utf8ToString()));
        }
    }
    documentTerms.Sort((word1, word2) => word1.Item1.CompareTo(word2.Item1));
    foreach (var word in documentTerms)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", fieldName, word.Item1, word.Item2);
    }
}
```

This code also handles the situation where you have the same term (word) in more than one place.